# Laravel/blade how to insert selected value to database

Tags: html, laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-blade

I am trying to store data from a select field to database.

I have tried this:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label>Type</label>
     <input style="width:10%" type="text" name="type" class="form-control" value="{{$findBook->type}}">
</div>
```

It displays from database and stores a new input to database - all good.

Then I have this what i need:

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple>
  @foreach($books as $book)
 <option value="{{ $book->type }}" {{ ( $book->type == $findBook->type) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{$book->type}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

This second part of the code displays data from databse in a select field, but does not update when I put it in a form instead of previous code part. Also tried to add `name="type"` .

I would appreciate any advice.

**Update**

My back end:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Book extends Model
    {
        protected $table = 'books';
        protected $fillable = ['title', 'type', 'description'];
    }
```

and

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {

       $emps = new Book;
       $emps->title = $request->input('title');
       $emps->type = $request->input('type');
       $emps->description = $request->input('description');
$emps->save();
    }
```

Insert request:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [

'title' => 'required',
'type' => 'required',
'description' => 'required',

        ];
```

Comment: returns error to you?please write more details about your problem

Comment: Updated. No errors. Just not updating. Shows same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for multiple select, you need to try `name="type[]"`

And on your `php` side, you should have `type` variable as `array`.

let me know if that helps.

Comment: Where would I put an array in my back end?

Comment: that's up to you, currently, is `type` just string? in your DB?

Answer (score 0):

PUT, Delete works with spoofing

In `<form>` tag use method post

```
<form method="POST">
```

and manually add at the end

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```